# how to grant user permissions

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using JS-SDK and my users already authorized with my facebook application.

now my open graph action is approved and started to publish.

my users are entering my website and JS SDK is automaticly taking login status with FB.getLoginStatus and doing stuff if user is logged to Facebook.

facebook is requiring "publish_actions" permission to publish actions on facebook. So, I added scope attiribute to my login button with "publish_actions" value and it's working when you click it.

but there is a problem : I didn't get this permission untill today from my users. So, I want to open a windows to accept this permission if user is not accepted this permission with JS SDK, automatically. Because the system is not doing this.

> Scenario(for more clear idea):
>
> 1) User came to my website last week and authorized with Login button.
>
> 2) I added Open Graph thing to my website and added scope attiribute to my login button yesterday.
>
> 3) User logged to Facebook. And after that came to my website today. JS SDK automatically authorized not gived any error to "there is new permissions on this website" or etc...
>
> So, I want to show new auth dialog to this user.

Comment: In my experience, this should happen automatically. You can test this by revoking your permission for your user account and logging into your app. You should get prompted to accept the new permission.

Comment: @AlexRockwell that's working but read my scenario please.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of what you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, once the user loads your page you can check with the js sdk what permissions the user granted your app, if the publish_actions is not included just ask him to grant it.

You can do it in the client side completely, something like this:

```
FB.api("me/permissions", function(response) {
    if (response && response.data && response.data.lengh == 1 && !("publish_actions" in response.data)) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, { scope: "publish_actions" });
    }
});
```

Or you can send the user to the auth dialog instead of calling *FB.login*, that's up to you.
Also, you can check the permissions in similar fashion on the server side and not client, again, it's up to you.

Comment: pop-up blocker blocking this code :/ so, I added a button to my website "if you want more good experience, click here and give permission" :/

Comment: Yes, of course, it says in the [FB.loging](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) documentation that: "*Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers*". The code was just to give you a nudge in the right direction. If it answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I added listener to document. So, when user clicks anywhere without this permission, it triggers fb.login. Problem solved :)